# How Do I Make Li Clickable for Radio Button Inside

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a fun form. This is what I have so far:

[>JSFiddle<](http://jsfiddle.net/zee9y3Lq/)

[>JSBin<](http://jsbin.com/yaqinozeyo/1/edit?html,css,output)

[>Codepen<](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxvMbg)

The html:

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="opinions" id="radio-1" />
            <label for="radio-1"></label>
            <label for="radio-1">Latest</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="opinions" id="radio-2" />
            <label for="radio-2"></label>
            <label for="radio-2">Random</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="opinions" id="radio-3" />
            <label for="radio-3"></label>
            <label for="radio-3">Favorites</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="opinions" id="radio-4" />
            <label for="radio-4"></label>
            <label for="radio-4">Most Views</label>
        </li>
        <ul>
</form>
```

and the css:

```
/*hide button & text label*/
input[type="radio"], input[type="radio"] + label + label {
    display: none;
}

/*Hide list bullets*/
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*Push label text down so it's not on image*/
input[type="radio"] + label + label {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/*display text label on hover*/
input[type="radio"]:hover + label + label, input[type="radio"] + label:hover + label,       input[type="radio"] + label + label:hover, ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 90px;
}

ul li {
     display: block;
     float:left;
     height: 60px;
     width: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid cyan;
     background: #555;
}

/*display picture that acts as radio button*/
 input#radio-1+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/53vskoxfl/time_added.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
/*change image color on hover & selected*/
 input#radio-1:checked+label, input#radio-1:hover+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/4jgri0475/time_added_selected.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input#radio-2+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/ew3242xq9/random.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input#radio-2:checked+label, input#radio-2:hover+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/cu2kptzr5/random_selected.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input#radio-3+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/c1uutip8h/favorites.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input#radio-3:checked+label, input#radio-3:hover+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/uiubhgbi9/favorites_selected.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input#radio-4+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/on0du1w75/views.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input#radio-4:checked+label, input#radio-4:hover+label {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/3re3it001/views_selected.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

So I'm pretty close to my goal. Which is to have the same style as the top menu links on [>wallhaven<](http://alpha.wallhaven.cc/search?categories=110&purity=100&sorting=random&order=desc). However, I want to make it into a radio option, where you can select one option. I also want to avoid using javascript if at all possible.

Questions:

1. The li isn't completely selectable/hoverable. How can I fix this. This is the main question.
2. Also, I don't believe I have to use the list, but rather just use radio buttons. Couldn't figure out how to avoid this. Anyway to avoid using a list?
3. Loading the images is really repetitive. Anyway to limit the repetition?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why the redundancy on `<label for="radio-?"></label>`?

Comment: First one to insert images that always appear. Second for text to hide/show. A lot of this was hack and slash and then trying to clean up. Didn't know of a better way to do this. Radio buttons are  really hard to customize.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I make the Li completely selectable/hoverable. Only the checkbox labels are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't make `li` element select your radios without using JavaScript. This element is static by design (presentation only). You can use labels to select a radio button, but to manage its states (and thus a visual representation thereof), you have to refer to JavaScript.
2. You don't have to use lists, you can just stack `labels` and radios, like in my forked code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPYaMj. I've also cleaned it up for you and made it work a bit better with a little help of jQuery.
3. You have basically two options: you can use an **image sprite**, or **icon fonts** (there's plenty of free ones and some can be custom-made for your needs).